# android:videochat(Unable to sign in in IMSDroid with the following configurations)

Tags: android, sip, voip, rtp

I am trying to make an Android application of video chat.For this i have created a account in SIP.I have received the Username  and password for the SIP server.I have implemented the IMS Droid project.But when i am signing the application using my SIP Display Name,IMS Public Identity (IMPU),IMS Private Identity (IMPI),Password,Realm and Network Settings i am not able to sign in.The indicator is showing red.Please suggest me to solve this.These are the informations i have given:

```
My Public Identity is sip:subhendu.das@sip2sip.info,
Realm is sip:sip2sip.info,
Private Identity is  subhendu.das@sip2sip.info,
Password is my chosen password.

In Networking Settings

Proxy:CSCF-Host is proxy.sipthor.net
Proxy:CSCF Port is 5060
Transport is UDP
Proxy:CSCF Discovery is none
In NAT Transversal ICE is enabled.
This is the link from where i get the informations :http://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/wiki/Quick_Start..
```

Please give me solution.

Answer (score 3):

From [a tutorial by PalmMicro](http://palmmicro.com/pa6488/software/userguide/sip.php):

> Click icon"Options", then icon "Identity" at home page, you can find
>   the identity configuration page as follows. The contents in the black
>   color are actual settings, while the contents in blue collor are
>   comments. Please go back to home page after finishing the settings.
>
> ![enter image description here][1]
>
> Click icon "Options", then icon"Network" will enter network
>   configuration page as follows. Please set according your network
>   environment. Go back to home page after settings.
>
> ![enter image description here][2]
>
> Click icon"Sign in" to login server. You will find seven more icons
>   at home page if login successfully.
>
> ![enter image description here][3]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4I2D.png   [2]:
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI7oz.png   [3]:
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvAwa.png